# Vagrant does not find machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

I want to have the machine in another IP:

```
  # Port forwarding
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "127.0.100.20"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", host_ip: "127.0.100.20", guest: 22, host: 47022
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", host_ip: "127.0.100.20", guest: 80, host: 47080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", host_ip: "127.0.100.20", guest: 443, host: 47443
```

But Vagrant still tries with the default IP:

```
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:47022
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
```

How can I tell Vagrant that the machine is bound to another IP?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following fact:

> By default, VirtualBox is the default provider for Vagrant. VirtualBox is still the most accessible platform to use Vagrant: it is free, cross-platform, and has been supported by Vagrant for years. With VirtualBox as the default provider, it provides the lowest friction for new users to get started with Vagrant.

[Source](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/default.html)

I conclude you need to add the following line to your configuration file.

```
virtualbox__intnet: true
```

Based on the following statement.

> The Vagrant VirtualBox provider supports using the private network as a VirtualBox internal network. By default, private networks are host-only networks, because those are the easiest to work with. However, internal networks can be enabled as well.
>
> To specify a private network as an internal network for VirtualBox use the virtualbox__intnet option with the network. The virtualbox__ (double underscore) prefix tells Vagrant that this option is only for the VirtualBox provider.

[Source](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/networking.html)

Comment: Or it’s possible the reason it’s not working is because of the [initial behavior by Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117939/vagrant-do-not-map-hostname-to-loopback-address-in-etc-hosts).  Would try defining the hostname for the Vagrant VM also per the configuration documentation.